# Slider Issue in Table View

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

In my app, i add a slider in Table view i.e. each row contains a slider & It also works fine.

But when i scroll the table view the slider get reload i.e. each shows me starting position rather than slider value.

```
//My code is as follow for slider in table cell:

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     NSString *CellIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellIdentifier%d",indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        return cell;
    }


    UISlider*  theSlider =  [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(174,12,120,23)] autorelease];
        theSlider.maximumValue=99;
        theSlider.minimumValue=0;
        [cell addSubview:theSlider];

return cell;
}
```

**How can i solve this issue??**

Answer (score 2):

You have to store the slider value, in an array etc and set your slider value according to array values in `cellforrowatindexpath`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d",indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UISlider*  theSlider =  [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(174,12,120,23)] autorelease];
        theSlider.maximumValue=99;
        theSlider.minimumValue=0;
        [cell addSubview:theSlider];
    }
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But sorry to say that this method is not working.

Comment: slider value is get reload & shows me on starting point rather than the slide value.

Comment: create the slider inside if(cell == nil) {  }. then set the value

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     NSString *CellIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellIdentifier%d",indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
UISlider*  theSlider = nil;
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

theSlider     =  [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(174,12,120,23)] autorelease];
        theSlider.maximumValue=99;
       theSlider.tag =2;
        theSlider.minimumValue=0;
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:theSlider];
    }



return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But sorry to say that this method is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I will need more code for a better answer. If this doesnt help you, please post your entire

```
-tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

method.

My guess right now qould be that you are setting up a new Slider every time you reuse a cell using

```
-tableView:dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
```

which (naturally) results in a new Slider in the starting position every time.

You will have to use a dictionary or an array of sliders that you can assign to the cells that are being reused.

For example, if yout TavbleView is supposed to have 20 rows, containing one slider each, you will need an array of 20 sliders and do something like

cell.slider = [mySliderArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]

That way, the sliders will preserve the value.

EDIT: try this: (i slightly modified your code pposted above)

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     NSString *CellIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellIdentifier%d",indexPath.row];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    return cell;
}

//This is where you went wrong
//UISlider*  theSlider =  [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(174,12,120,23)] autorelease];
    //theSlider.maximumValue=99;
    //theSlider.minimumValue=0;
    //[cell addSubview:theSlider];

//this is what you need to do:
[cell addSubview: [mySlidersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


return cell;
}
```

Obviously, you need to set up an array of Sliders called ´mySlidersArray´ somewhere in viewDidload or whatever.

NEXT EDIT:
Here's how i would create that array of sliders:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfSliders = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 20];
for (int i =0; i<20; i++){
    UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] init];
    //set the slider-properties here, like you already did in your code
    [arrayOfSliders addObject: slider];
}
```

Now those sliders are accessible like in my code above.

Another way is to keep an array of Values for the sliders, and set the sliders to those values after instantiating them. But that would result in very poor performance, since a new slider would be created for every cell that comes on screen.

Let me know if you need more help and
have fun

Comment: how can i create an array of 20 sliders??

Comment: Well, obviously you are able to create one slider. You did it in your code. Now make twenty copies and put them in an array. You might want to use a loop for that.

Comment: @user1673099 I have updates my answer with code to create the array of sliders. let me know how it works